# IIS Express web api configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I understand nearly nothing about this. Any knowledge will be appreciated.

My application uses configuration files which are need to be written to the bin folder of my application. However those files are currently being written to IIS/Express folder.

How do I change it?

Is this somehow related to virtual directories configuration of IIS express?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? Unless you are using VS2015, the config is user wide and resides in your My Document folder.

Comment: When I try creating a folder in my iis I get a access violation exception. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it would be hard to give an answer, but it is very likely you use the wrong way to access the path. Microsoft has a summary here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx